# FTP upload issue - vsftpd ubuntu14

Tags: ftp, upload, ubuntu-14.04

I have been struggling for hours to resolve this. Could someone please tell me what am I missing as it is driving me insane.

Filezilla error code:

```
  Response: 553 Could not create file
```

All the settings that are enabled in /etc/vsftpd.conf

```
  local_enable=YES
  write_enable=YES
  connect_from_port_20=YES
  chroot_local_user=YES
```

Folder Permissions added:

```
sudo chown -R bob:bob folder/
```

Restarted process:

```
service vsftpd restart
```

I have also disabled the firewall, so its not a firewall issue.
I have installed getenforce, how do I give you guys the output you need?

Comment: Output of `getenforce`?

Comment: Sorry, I have installed in now. How do I give you the output you need ?

Comment: Edit it into your question?

Comment: I have added it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved my own question.

I created the user bob and made his home directory the FTP directory. The home directroy then didnt have write permissions which I enabled.

Then I discovered vsftpd does not allow you to write to your home directory via ftp.

Here is the solution to enable vsftpd to write to your home directory via ftp.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420177/500-oops-vsftpd-refusing-to-run-with-writable-root-inside-chroot-login-faile